# Is CMAccelerometerData event time stamp UTC value?

Tags: ios, accelerometer

In iOS, I'm using event time stamp available from the event (CMAccelerometerData*) 
I want to know whether its referencing from the year 2001 or 1970?
I couldn't find proper document that explains the time stamp details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timestamp provided by CMAccelerometerData is the amount of time in seconds since the phone booted.

So you first have to get phone's boot time, like this:

```
let bootTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -NSProcessInfo.processInfo().systemUptime)
```

And then you can get the real date for the Accelerometer event:

```
let eventDate = NSDate(timeInterval: data.timestamp, sinceDate: bootTime)
```

I see that you asked this 25 days ago, but i hope it still be useful for anyone.

Comment: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1414553-systemuptime) say that `systemUptime` is defined as ```The amount of time the system has been awake since the last time it was restarted.``` The key word here is `awake`, which means that the clock stops counting when the CPU is asleep. So, you cannot compute the system boot date from this value.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for Swift 4/5**

```
let bootTime = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime)
let eventDate = Date(timeInterval: data.timestamp, since: bootTime)
```